# Higher dimensional Manifolds

Tags: manifolds

I know  these manifolds can be expressed as constraint equations. For example if we consider a sphere embedded in a 3D Euclidean space, the sphere can actually be expressed in a set of intrinsic coordinates restricted to the manifold.For example we can use polar coordinates.
But what I am wondering is these are just 2 dimensional and 3 dimensional. Are there any specific examples for higher dimensional embeddings?

Comment: The $n$-sphere $S^n=\{ (x_1, x_2, \cdots, x_n) |\sum_{i\leq n} x_i^2=1\}$ can be shown to be a smooth manifold endowed with coordinates given by constraint equations. In general, a powerful tool for showing that the set of solutions to some constraint equation is a smooth manifold in a natural way is done using the "Regular value theorem".

Comment: @J.V.Gaiter Have you got any references?

Comment: This is covered in Lee's book on smooth manifolds in the chapter on submanifolds.